# Why doesn't PSE circuit maintain power to PD?

Tags: power, poe

I am trying to make a PoE 802.3af solution. This are my schematics:

[image: PSE]

[image: PD]

The problem is that the power does not maintain. It only provides 48V for about 300ms, then it drops. Also, the above statement is valid when I remove the DC converter input capacitor; I tried a 22uF, 47uF, 22uF, 100uF capacitor, but every time I connect the capacitor, the PSE (LTC4263) does not supply power, instead it indicates low signature resistance by flashing the LED with a specific pattern.

**What is causing this behavior and how can it be resolved? What capacitor should I use?**

Comment: These are the oscilloscope captures: [voltage across D1 diode](https://ibb.co/iyFzMG) and [PG output](https://ibb.co/df3sab).

Comment: Don't write comments on your question. Rather, add the additional information into the question so that all the relevant stuff is in the right place.

Comment: @Transistor I wanted to include all information in the question, but it said that I do not have enough reputation to add 3 images.

Comment: Just type them in. Someone with enough rep will convert them to links for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've tested the PD module with a commercial PSE and it worked. It seems that the problem is related with my PSE.